# Angular Rxjs: syntax error using pipeable operators

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm trying to re-write this code:

```
Observable
    .merge(this.searchQuery$, this.lazyQuery$)
    .do(() => this.loadingPage())
    .map(filter => this.buildURL("jaume", Config.security['appName'], filter))
    .switchMap(url =>
        this.service.getItemsFromStorage(url)
        .map(response => this.buildPage(response))
        .catch(() => Observable.of(pojo.Page.EMPTY))
    )
    .do(page => this.loadedPage(page))
    .takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)
    .subscribe();
```

I want to use "pipable" syntax. Up to now, I've been able to write that:

```
this.searchQuery$.pipe(
    merge(this.lazyQuery$),
    tap(() => this.loadingPage()),
    map(filter => this.buildURL("jaume", Config.security['appName'], filter))
)
.pipe(
    switchMap(url => this.service.getItemsFromStorage(url)),
    catchError(() => Observable.of(pojo.Page.EMPTY))
)
.pipe(
    tap(page => this.loadedPage(page))  <<***>>
);
```

I'm getting a compiler error on `<<***>>`:

> Argument of type 'Response | Page' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Page'.
>     Type 'Response' is missing the following properties from type 'Page': total, users

It seems that `catchError` is returning `{} | Page` type, when it should return a single `Page` type.

Any ideas?

Comment: You don't need that many pipes. One pipe is just enough for one workflow

Comment: Could you provide an answer showing your approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed to map a `response` to a `page`.

```ts
merge(this.searchQuery$, this.lazyQuery$).pipe(
  tap(() => this.loadingPage()),
  map(filter => this.buildURL("jaume", Config.security['appName'], filter)),
  switchMap(url => this.service.getItemsFromStorage(url).pipe(
    map(response => this.buildPage(response)), // <-- you missed this map in your code
    catchError(() => of(pojo.Page.EMPTY))
  )),
  tap(page => this.loadedPage(page)),
  takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)
).subscribe();
```

Also check out the official migration guide: [Howto: Convert to pipe syntax](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md#howto-convert-to-pipe-syntax)

Answer (score 1):

First of all there is too many pipes. There is no need for so many. Also you may use `of()` instead of `Observable.of()` which is quite shorter and IMHO easier to read.

```
this.searchQuery$.pipe(
    merge(this.lazyQuery$),
    tap(() => this.loadingPage()),
    map(filter => this.buildURL("jaume", Config.security['appName'], filter)),
    switchMap(url => this.service.getItemsFromStorage(url)),
    catchError(() => of(pojo.Page.EMPTY)),
    tap(page => this.loadedPage(page))  <<***>>
);
```

This will work just fine.

Your error is not about what it returns but what TypeScript **thinks** it returns. So you have to just say it what it returns. For example

```
...
catchError(() => of(<Page>pojo.Page.EMPTY))
...
```

If this really is about `catchError` section.

### Update #1 - Nesting

If you need to apply some specific pipe to the only one point in a chain then you should add this pipe where an observable is returned. For example

```
...
switchMap(() => of(null).pipe(
  catchError(...)
))
```

When you do

```
.pipe(...),
.pipe(...),
.pipe(...),
```

This is an equivalent of

```
.pipe(
...
...
...
)
```

Comment: I miss a lot of details on your approach. 1) What about nested `switchMap(...).catch(...) method? It's very important to keep this nesting chain otherwise when an error raises subscription is dropped out. 2) I don't think TypeScript thinks or it doesn't. Just in case I've tested your approach, and problem keeps there. Sorry.

Comment: This error is a TypeScript erorr. Also this error clearly points the position of a problem. If you use some powerful IDE like WebStorm it also should show where it is thanks to code analysis